# Error message 'unclosed %DO statement' for sas macro to compare two numeric values

Tags: macros, sas

I am using the macro below to compare two numeric values as part of an exercise.

```
options mlogic mprint;

%let price_trd = 93.68;

%put &price_trd.;

%let max_price = 100.94;

%put &max_price.;

%macro test;

  %if  &price_trd. < &max_price %then %do;
%if  %sysevalf(&price_trd. LT &max_price) %then %do;

  %put Pass HERE;

  %end;

%mend;

%test;
```

I am getting the errors below:
There is one unclosed %DO statement.
The macro was not compiled.

Please let me know our advice to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you have two %DO statements and only one %END statement. Looks to me like you should delete the first %if statement. You will need %sysevalf because your values are not integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not state/instruct in your code what has to happen with first %if and %do condition and also did not close the %do with %end. try something like below.

```
%macro test;

    %if  &price_trd. < &max_price %then %do;
        %put something HERE;
    %end;
   %if  %sysevalf(&price_trd. > &max_price) %then %do;
      %put Pass HERE;
  %end;
 %mend;

%test;
```